when using Apryse/PDFTron WebViewer, why does a red "Draft" image appear over PDF?
when using Apryse/PDFTron WebViewer, why does a red "Draft" image appear over PDF?

How to avoid the unexpected red "Draft" image from appearing over the PDF?
Does anyone know what triggers the red "Draft" image to appear?
Is it a built-in image in Apryse/PDFTron WebViewer?

@KJ: I'm using PDFTron/WebViewer8.12.3. This red Draft image only appears 1 out of 100 times (not all the time). I'm unable to find a pattern to reproduce it... the bug just comes and goes :(

@KJ: My screenshot was taken from my local machine which doesn't use PDFTron license. That's why my screenshot has the blue PDFTRON  watermark which represents demo mode.
But my company's production server indeed uses PDFTron license (no watermark, NOT in demo mode). And this red "draft" marker appears on PDF file on production server 1 out of 100 times.

@KJ: It appears in one PDF once and doesn't appear in the same PDF any more. Then, it appears in the 2nd PDF once and disappear. There is no pattern. Nothing is repeated. The red draft shows up at different locations in different PDF. When I test the same PDF with the same flow next time, the red Draft just doesn't appear again.
I already asked tech support of vendor(Apryse/PDFTron webviewer). They only responded that they are unable to reproduce it. They didn't respond to my question "what triggers the red Draft image to appear?". That's why I came to stackoverflow.

@KJ: you mean to attach the PDF file in the question? I just tried, but there is no "attach file" option when I edit the question.

@KJ: >(so they seem to generate it but dont know how !!!)
correct.
I remember I read it somewhere in google that the red Draft image is a "fallback" image of Apryse/PDFTron Webviewer when a custom image fails to be uploaded.
(Unfortunately, I'm unable to find the article on google any more.)
But I see the bug in PDF files that do NOT have any custom images on the production server(which has valid license).
That's why I asked tech support of Apryse/PDFTron "what triggers the red Draft image to appear?".
But they didn't answer....   :(

@KJ: My company is NOT using pirate copy. We pay  license of Apryse/PDFTron Webviewer every year. We do use older version(v8) of Apryse/PDFTron Webviewer, but we are using older version of OFFICIAL LICENSED one.

@KJ: It just occurred to me why you misunderstand that I am using a pirate copy. I can't explain details, but I swear that I'm not using a pirate copy and my company absolutely pay license fee for Apryse/PDFTron Webviewer every year. Thank you for the help. I really appreciate it.

@K J: The PDF court form was downloaded from court website and edited by a previous employee in my company 7 years ago.  He used a PDF editor tool (I don’t know the tool name) to edit PDF court form. That weird stamp you saw came from that PDF editor tool 7 years ago.  
3 years ago, my company bought license from PDFTron webviewer, then used PDFTron webviewer on those old edited PDF court forms.
I know almost nothing about PDF, let alone how to parse PDF.
Could you please tell me which tool you used to parse PDF to see those weird stamps? I'm trying to parse it to see the red Draft stamp.

@K J: right, it makes sense. It's possible.

Government and Other major organisations use Adobe specific Proprietary Features driven by internal programming. They have been especially designed to only work correctly in an Adobe licensed XFA editor such as Acrobat Reader DC and include hidden features.
The problem here is that a 3rd Party modified the OLD 2016 DRAFT PDF cover from an XFA structure form. Possibly not using Adobe products as there is no sign of California Gov 2018 Draft or Later 2023 Adobe official markers. The source of the 3 stamps is shown as a Commercial organisation originalFieldName":"\\"77373lawyaw_prefixuntagged_77373\\
If it was an official copy it would show :

If it was the current OFFICIAL XFA it would show as:


Such Acro[bat-ch]forms especially these XFA varieties (where a form is wrapped within a PDF cover page) should not and often do not work the same in other editors or applications.
We can see below in ADOBE Acrobat the CIV-140 form presents no such markings.
There are scripted functions for Users "print and save" that should only be used there by clients.
Generally as the form is PERSONAL to the filler, there is no need for programmable applications to be used by 3rd parties. However they may be used by the parent org or their agents, in conjunction with bulk submittal imports/exports via Adobe FDF (Forms Data Field) for Submit buttons and or HTTPS/MIME AEM functionality.


@K J: > We can see below in ADOBE Acrobat the CIV-140 form presents no such markings.
Yes, the original CIV-140 form from the court's website does not have the red Draft marking.
The red Draft marking comes from Apryse/PDFTron WebViewer.
I'm trying to figure out what triggers Apryse/PDFTron WebViewer to show the red Draft marking...

@K J: It's a legal PDF. After we downloaded it from the court website, we modified it in PDF editor first. Then, we apply licensed PDFTron webviewer.
p.s. PDFTron's Tech support just replied to me:
The DRAFT image is the default visual for the Stamp annotation as defined by the PDF spec, so DRAFT would appear slightly different in each viewer. The DRAFT image is shown if the appearance for the image failed, its sort of a "fallback" image.
p.s. PDFTron's Tech support only replies to customers who have a license key.
License key is required in
https://apryse.com/form/request
